# Stop tableView scrolling under status bar (Swift 5, Xcode 15)

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, statusbar

I have a tableView inside -> navigationViewController -> tabBarController.

[image]

The tableView keeps scrolling under the statusBar no matter what I do. I like it to stop underneath the status bar.

All viewControllers are configured the standard way. I configured them in many different ways and tried many combinations.

[image]

No matter what I do the tableView keeps scrolling under the status bar.

[image]

I didn't felt the need to configure that in code, but I just adjusting contentInset's and scrollIndicatorInset's without success.

```
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

The adjustment just pushes the tableView another 20px down.

[image]

This is the size of the tableView at the moment. I did the background orange for clarity.

[image]

Comment: What does 'to stop tableView from scrolling under status bar' mean?  You mean, not to show the table view right under the status bar?

Comment: Yes. I like to have the status bar opaque and have the tableView end underneath the status bar.

Comment: Did you tried to clip scrollview content so it can not display outside scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "have the status bar opaque". It is transparent. You can put something behind it if you want to see that color through it.

The problem with the scrolling, however, is merely that your autolayout constraints are wrong. The table view scrolls behind the status bar because the table view *is* behind the status bar. Because *you put it there*. To stop the table view from being behind the status bar, just pin its top to the *safe area top* with a constant of 0. The safe area top is the status bar bottom (in this situation).

[image]